forest - Centering root node tree using folder for an organigram (organisational chart)
This is my last resort trying to understand the best way to center the root node on an organigram I made. The problem is caused - I think - by the use of folder that is required for this. Without the use of folder, the horizontal position of the root node makes visual sense to me:

However, I'd like to format it as follows with folder, where I would like the center node to center on the middle child:

From my limited understanding and reading of the manual of Forest, perhaps I could somehow delay the alignment of the root node, but I have not be able to do so.
Any help would be much appreciated!
BONUS: If the root node can be centered on the middle child, then of course the rounded edges will cause a problem. I have not idea how to fix that yet, but one step at a time for me (but two for whoever can solve that as well...)
    my organigram/.style={
        baseline,anchor=north,
        for tree={
            draw,
            edge+={rounded corners},
            /tikz/align=center
            text width = 3cm,
            minimum height = 1cm,
            if level=1{text width = 3cm}{},
            if level>=1{folder, grow'=0}{for children=forked edge, s sep=1cm} %COMMENT OUT FOR FIRST EXAMPLE
        }
    }
}

\begin{forest}
    my organigram
        [\textcolor{red}{↓ should align ↓}
            [first child
                [x
                    [x]
                    [x]
                    [x]
                    [x]
                    [x]
                    [x]
                    [x]
                    [x]  
                ]
            ]
            [x
                [x
                    [x]
                    [x]
                ]
            ]
            [\textcolor{red}{↑ should align ↑}
                [x
                    [x]
                ]
                [x]
            ]
            [x
                [x]
                [x]
                [x]
            ]
            [last child
                [x]
                [x]
            ]        
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}


Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

calign with current edge aligns the parent's edge with the current node's child anchor, which is what you want here. I'm not sure which edges you don't want to have rounded corners. If you don't want them at all, just remove that line. If you want them only for the leaves, you can apply the option in for leaves. For example,
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\forestset{%
  my organigram/.style={
    baseline,anchor=north,
    for leaves={edge+=rounded corners},
    for tree={
      draw,
%       edge+={rounded corners},
      /tikz/align=center,
      text width = 3cm,
      minimum height = 1cm,
%       if level=1{text width = 3cm}{},
      if level>=1{folder, grow'=0}{for children=forked edge, s sep'=1cm} %COMMENT OUT FOR FIRST EXAMPLE
    },
  },
}

\begin{forest}
    my organigram
        [\textcolor{red}{↓ should align ↓}
            [first child
                [x
                    [x]
                    [x]
                    [x]
                    [x]
                    [x]
                    [x]
                    [x]
                    [x]  
                ]
            ]
            [x
                [x
                    [x]
                    [x]
                ]
            ]
            [\textcolor{red}{↑ should align ↑}, calign with current edge
                [x
                    [x]
                ]
                [x]
            ]
            [x
                [x]
                [x]
                [x]
            ]
            [last child
                [x]
                [x]
            ]        
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}


I commented out the if level=1 etc. because you're already applying precisely the same option to all nodes in the tree, so there's no point also applying it a second time to those in level 1.
Personally, I would remove rounded corners rather than having it apply only to the leaves, but that's obviously a matter of preference.

I found the solution, thanks to a combination of anchor=west, and calign=midpoint. To solve the rounded edges between root and middle child, I gave the latter a straight edge.
Note, however, that this only works if all the nodes are the same size. Changing text width to e.g. 4 cm puts everything out of whack again.
\forestset{
    my organigram/.style={
        baseline,anchor=north,
        for tree={
            draw,
            edge+={rounded corners},
            /tikz/align=center,
            text width=3cm,
            minimum height=1cm,
            rounded corners,
            if level=0{anchor=west}{},
            if level=1{text width = 3cm}{},
            if level>=1{folder, grow'=0}{for children=forked edge, s sep=1cm}
        }
    }
}

\begin{forest}
    my organigram
        [\textcolor{red}{↓ should align ↓}, calign=midpoint
            [first child
                [x
                    [x]
                    [x]
                    [x]
                    [x]
                    [x]
                    [x]
                    [x]
                    [x]  
                ]
            ]
            [x
                [x
                    [x]
                    [x]
                ]
            ]
            [\textcolor{red}{↑ should align ↑}, edge={sharp corners}
                [x
                    [x]
                ]
                [x]
            ]
            [x
                [x]
                [x]
                [x]
            ]
            [last child
                [x]
                [x]
            ]        
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}



You don't need sharp corners. There are no corners in the edge to be sharp or round.
